# InstallR fails on MacOS 10.15 (Catalina)

Tags: warning-messages, external-calls

Here is code I evaluated and the error message:

```
Needs["RLink`"];
SetEnvironment[
  "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"->"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib"]
InstallR[
  "RHomeLocation"->"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources","RVersion"->3];
```

> InstallR::fail: Failed to install R. The following error was encountered: Unable to load dynamic libraries

The same code ran successfully with the previous MacOS versions (El Captain, Mojave)

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

In Mathematica 12.0, the documentation for `InstallR`says:

If "RHomeLocation" is set to a specific location, this enables RLink to use external R distribution, where the specified location should correspond to the setting of the R_HOME variable (point at the root of R distribution). This option is currently supported on Windows only.

So what you did should not have worked for macOS versions earlier than Catalina, either!

(I do wish WRI would allow the use of external R distributions for Mac, too!)

Comment: I did read the sentence "This option is currently supported on Windows only.". But working with Mojave I sued exactly RHomeLocation and it worked for log time.

Comment: What do you suggest as an equivalent command to run InstallR with Mathematica12  and Catalina? Actually, I used RHomeLocation with Mathematica 10.

Comment: I mean. The R version in the paclet is 2.14.0, while I need the version 3.6.2 the libraries such as polyreg and regtools are available.

Comment: solved!! following the suggestions at the link https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1807709